# problem with php code to add longitude and latitude

Tags: php, geolocation

Basically, I have this code to get IP address information.
It stores the data in a Txt file.
How could I add the longitude and latitude to this code, to get an Accurate result, not an approximate.

I found this code and tried to use it but its written in html while my code is in php.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

```
<?php 
//IP Grabber 
//Variables 
$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
//Print IP, Hostname, Port Number, User Agent and Referer To Log.TXT 
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fh, 'IP Address: '."".$ip ."\n");
fwrite($fh, 'Hostname: '."".$hostname ."\n");
fwrite($fh, 'Port Number: '."".$port ."\n");
fwrite($fh, 'User Agent: '."".$agent ."\n");
fwrite($fh, 'HTTP Referer: '."".$ref ."\n\n");
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

I am expecting to get the same results plus the Longitude and Latitude info

Comment: You need to use an IP geolocation service, like MaxMind.

Comment: longitude and latitude, generally known as 'location' is provided by the browser ONLY if the user allows sharing location. Secondly the location is not accurate for desktop or even laptops. A mobile device, however, may provide a more accurate info. Nevertheless the location is available to the client-side script, not php. You would have to collect the info from browser and submit it to server to save it, again ONLY if user allow.